# Can I upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 via an ISO image?

Tags: upgrade, iso, 13.04

I want to upgrade to 13.04 beta, but I don't want to upgrade through the terminal as I can't download 700mb from home, but I can download an ISO image from where I go to school. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very possible and I would do it except my computer is too old. 
I think you might be able to just download the ISO and put it on a USB via UNetBootin/Startup Disk Creator (the unpacked image is now too large for most CDs) and then boot the ISO from the USB drive. 
I believe the startup disk will recognize you have a lower version installed and give you the option of upgrading from the disk.

Best of luck!